# How do I return a boolean value and TestConnectionCommand+PingStatus when using Test-Connection in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ping

`$success = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 4 -TimeoutSeconds 3 -TargetName $ip`
This code return the TestConnectionCommand+PingStatus while,

`$success = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 4 -TimeoutSeconds 3 -TargetName $ip -Quiet`
This code returns a boolean value

The question is, how do i return both TestConnectionCommand+PingStatus and boolean value with only send the pings once.

Comment: Why don't you check for the property `Status -eq 'Success'`?

Comment: `$?` you can give this a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ping = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 4 -TimeoutSeconds 3 -TargetName $ip

for ($p = 0; $p -lt $ping.length; $p++) {

    if($ping[$p].Status -eq "Success"){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $ping[$p].Status
        $result = "True"
    }else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $p.Status
        $result = "False"
        break
    }
}
$result | Out-File -LiteralPath $store -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

The command does not return anything if it fails to ping without -Quiet. Then check the status.

```
$success = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 4 -TimeoutSeconds 3 -TargetName $ip -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($success -and ($success.Status -eq "Success")) {
# do something with the $success
}
else {
# connection failed
}
```